# Standard name for a certain inner product on a polynomial ring

Tags: representation-theory, terminology, inner-products

In Goodman and Wallach's book *Symmetry, Representations, and Invariants* (2009 edition), on page 231 (proof of Lemma 5.1.5), the authors introduce an inner product $\langle\:,\:\rangle$ on the space $\mathbb C[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, defined as follows:
$$
\langle f,g\rangle := \partial(f)\overline{g}(0),
$$
where $\partial(f)$ is the differential operator determined by the map $x_i \longmapsto \partial/\partial x_i$, and $\overline{g}$ is the polynomial whose coefficients are the complex conjugates of those in $g$.  It follows that for multi-indices $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb N^n$, we have $\langle x^\alpha,x^\beta\rangle = \alpha!$ if $\alpha = \beta$, and $0$ otherwise.

Is this inner product attested to elsewhere in the literature?  Does it have a standard name?  For example, is it at all related to the Hall inner product on symmetric polynomials?  In recent research I appeal to the fact that $\langle \:,\:\rangle$ yields an invariant pairing under the action of $\operatorname{GL}_n$ on $\mathbb C[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, but I would like to reference this properly.